# Background linear-gradient with rgba does not show up in google chrome android but works fine in chrome desktop

Tags: android, css

I used [cssgradient.io](https://cssgradient.io/) to generate a liner-gradient which is half transparent, the code works fine in Firefox mobile, and chrome desktop but the linear gradient does not work on chrome android mobile application. The div name is `gradient-patch` that is overlays on top of the video

I am using video js plugin for hls support in my video. 
Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8xk46p3a/3/).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link
   href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700&display=swap"
   rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>


  <div class="container">
   <!-- Video Container -->
   <div class="video-container">
    <video
     width="500"
     height="500"
     preload="auto"
     class="video videojs"
     id="video"
     autoplay = "true"
    >
     <source
      src="https://bs-hls-video-output.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/video-quiz/index.m3u8"
      type="application/x-mpegURL"
     />
    </video>https://jsfiddle.net/8xk46p3a/3/#
    <div class="gradient-patch"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- Question -->
   <div class="question-cotainer question-active">
    <div class="question-index">Question :</div>
    <div class="question">
     What is the capital of India ?
    </div>
    <div class="options">
     <div class="option">
      Kerala
     </div>
     <div class="option">
      Delhi
     </div>
     <div class="option">
      Bangalore
     </div>
     <div class="option">
      Pune
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.5/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.15.0/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background-color: #0d223d;
 color: white;
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.video-container {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 500px;
}

.video {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
}

/* Question */

.question-cotainer {
 display: none;
}

.question {
 font-size: 28px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 1rem;
}

.question-index {
 margin: 1rem;
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: 700;
}

/* Options */

.options {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.option {
 background-color: #143571;
 padding: 0.6rem 3rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 border-radius: 50px;
 font-size: 22px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.option:hover {
 background-color: #2356b4;
}

.modal {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
 z-index: 10;
}

.btn {
 border: 0;
 padding: 1rem 3rem;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-primary {
 background-color: #2356b4;
}

.abs-center {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal-active {
 display: block;
}

.question-active {
 display: block;
}

.gradient-patch {
 width: 500px;
 height: 100px;

 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 bottom: 0;

 background: rgb(13, 34, 61);
 background: linear-gradient(
  0deg,
  rgba(13, 34, 61, 1) 0%,
  rgba(13, 34, 61, 0) 100%
 );
}
```

**JS**

```
var player = videojs("video");
 player.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a pre/postprocessor that takes care of browser prefixes have you tried adding the

```
-webkit-
-o-
-moz-
```

prefixes to your linear gradient? eg.

```
background: linear-gradient(
  0deg,
  rgba(13, 34, 61, 1) 0%,
  rgba(13, 34, 61, 0) 100%
 );
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
  0deg,
  rgba(13, 34, 61, 1) 0%,
  rgba(13, 34, 61, 0) 100%
 );
background: -o-linear-gradient(...);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(...);
```

Comment: Got them from https://blog.prototypr.io/css-only-multi-color-backgrounds-4d96a5569a20 if you're interested

Comment: Added css prefixes which is auto generated by cssgradient.io never worked

Comment: What version of chrome for android are you testing on?